# Getting data from Firebase real-time on react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have a js file that is initializing the firebase database, I want to connect to the firebase realtime database and fetch the relevant information.

The function I'm calling:

```
get getName() {
var ref = firebase.database().ref('variable').child('variable').child('variable');

ref.on('value', gotData, errData);



function gotData(data) {

    console.log(data.val());
    console.log(data.val().ogrIsim + 'getname calisti');
    console.log(String(data.val().ogrIsim));
    this.setState({
        name: (data.val().ogrIsim)
    });
    // return String(data.val().ogrIsim);
}

function errData(err) {
    console.log('errorrrr!!!' + err);
}
```

}

console.log (data.val (). [variableName]); I print console as a string in the line, but I can't change it because it says there is an object that is not a string in setstate e. How should I proceed?

and the error message :

[image]

Comment: Are you facing error while setting state? If Yes, please share the error.

Comment: I think you're looking for `dersAdi: data.val()[VariableNAME]`, so minus the `.` after `val()`.

Comment: i added error message and update the code block .

Comment: I try this. without '.' statement but didnt work @Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message happens because `this` has a different meaning inside the `gotData` function than outside of it.

There are many ways to address this, but in this case an explicit `bind()` might be easiest:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('variable').child('variable').child('variable');

ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function gotData(data) {
  this.setState({ name: (data.val().ogrIsim) });
}.bind(this);
function errData(err) {
  console.log('errorr' + err);
}
```

For much more on this, see [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)